# No result on sqlite query

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi all
I create a table like that

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PRODUCT =
 "create table prod (id integer primary key,titre text not null, desc text, is_free integer);";
```

i update it this way

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = getConnection();
    ContentValues updateEvent = new ContentValues();
    updateEvent.put("is_free", 1);

    int ok = db.update(prod, updateEvent, "id=?",
            new String[] { Long.toString(evenement.getId()) });

    db.close();
```

I do see the change in eclipse with DDMS questoid

but when i try to retrieve the value I get nothing ....

```
        Cursor c = db.query(prod, new String[] { "id",
                "titre", "desc", "is_free", }, 
                 "is_free=?", new String[] {"1"}, null, null,
                null);
```

I've tried some variant like

```
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+EVENEMENT_TABLE+" WHERE is_free=1;";
    Cursor c = sdb.rawQuery(query, null);
```

with no success

is this problem come from the type (integer) of my column ?
Any help

Comment: this way works        Cursor c = db.query(prod, new String[] { "id",
                "titre", "desc", "is_free", }, 
                 "is_free=1", , null, null,
                null);

Answer (score 0):

Do not use reserved keywords like `desc` in your queries. This probably causes query to fail.
In case you don't know `update` will not add values to the table. Use `insert` instead.